# WordSearch: Name for ontology practitioner?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper name for a practitioner of ontology? Note that there are also philosophers of ontology, who are not practitioners (they don't use ontologies).

Comment: Well, I suppose you'd call them an **ontologist**, although I've never encountered anyone whose sole job was to name things.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ontologist

Comment: Here is an example of practitioners of ontologies: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/services/ontologies

Comment: as soon as I wrote that I thought *"ah, wait, but in the biological sciences, naming things is actually a pretty big job, I bet someone proves me wrong"*. :)

Comment: So you want a word for someone who uses these things in contrast to someone who talks about these things? E.g. scientist vs engineer, manager vs worker, widget assembly line overseer vs widget assembly line slot #73? It's just ontologist.

Comment: @Mitch: I guess you're right though a quick google search doesn't produce anything 'formal'. That's really what I was looking for: a formal reference.

Answer (score 2):

Ontologist would probably be the most appropriate. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ontologist

Comment: I would give you a +1 for the link if it were not for the way dictionary.com are sneaky. Did you notice that the only place where the word 'ontologist' occurs is in the search box?

Comment: Thanks! Very thoughtful of you! Well this place is looking to hire an "ontologist", I guess they do exist. http://www.bullhornreach.com/job/1826428_ontologist-knowledge-architect-springfield-ma

Comment: OK... you've earned your cookie. ;-)